# Can't get ifstream object declared as a member in my class

Tags: c++

i am trying to read from a file in multiple places in my class functions. Therefor i thought it would be smart to declare the object in the headerfile(in private) but after i did that it does not work anymore

I did use the search function and found something about copy constructors might be the problem but i don't really know what they do and why i need to change something about them(if that is even the case in my code)

**command.h:**

```
class command
{
public:

command();
~command();
void printCommands() const;

private:
std::ifstream file;

}
```

**Command.cpp**

```
command::command(){
file.open("commands.txt");
}
command::~command()
{
file.close();
}
void command::printCommands() const
{
int i = 0;

std::string line;
std::cout <<"Command list:\n\n";

while (getline(file,line))
{
    std::cout << line <<endl<<endl;
}
}
```

This is just a part of the code but basicly i get an errror at the getline function

i get this error

```
 error C2665: 'std::getline' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types
 std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::getline<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<_Ty>>      (std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &&,std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)
```

**edit1:**

I did forget, if i do move the

```
 std::ifstream file;
```

into the cpp functions (where i use the getline functions) it works without a problem, but shouldn't it work with the declarition in private?

Answer (score 2):

Your `command::printCommands()` is declared const. Since `file` is a member, you are trying to pass a `const ifstream&` as a non-const `std::istream&` parameter (received by `std::getline`).

The conversion looses the `const` qualifier on call (so compilation fails with the error you got).

To fix, remove the const qualifier from `command::printCommands()`.

Comment: @AlexanderTobiasHeinrich, that would work (but I think it is wrong semantically). I see mutable as something that doesn't belong to the values of an object (for example, complex results cached in the object for efficiency). Since the code modifies the file object state, I think it is incorrect to mark the file as mutable (even though it fixes the compiler error).

Comment: One could argue, that it is equally wrong to mark a member function as `const` if it alters the internal state of its objects....

Comment: @AlexanderTobiasHeinrich, Yes I think this is the case (i.e. marking the function as const is wrong in this situation).

Comment: Ok I changed it from const so now it is like this:
void command::printCommands() //this is .cpp file
void printCommands(); //this is .h file
Still doesnt work i get this error:
NVM my bad it works now thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
void command::printCommands() const
```

That line declares `printCommands()` to be a const function. I.e., one that does not change the `command` object. Reading from an input stream is a change, so if the input stream is part of the `command` then reading from it necessarily changes the `command`.

I don't know your program so I can't say whether the following is a good idea or not, but it should make the error go away: declare `file` as a mutable member:

```
mutable std::ifstream file;
```